# User property to skip running tests but still compile them in Surefire 3.x

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin, maven-failsafe-plugin

The [Maven Surefire Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/) documentation says I can use the [`skipTests`](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#skipTests) user property to keep from running tests, but still compile them. However it says that this approach is deprecated and will be removed in Failsafe 3.0.0.

There is also a [`maven.test.skip`](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#skip) user property, but this bypasses compiling tests altogether.

So what user property am I supposed to use in Surefire 3.x if I want to compile tests and but run them? *Note that my question is about setting a user property in the Maven POM, not a Java system property I specify on the command line.* Is this capability being removed altogether from Surefire 3.x?

Note that the [Maven Failsafe Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/) still has a [`skipITs`](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#skipITs) user property which is *not* deprecated, and which compiles integration tests but does not run them.

Comment: "_will be removed in Failsafe 3.0.0_" shouldn't affect Surefire, should it?

Comment: Ohhhh, thank you Gerold. Going back and forth between Surefire and Failsafe documentation makes it easy to read one and think the other. So the idea seems to be that `skipTests` should continue to be used in Surefire. Maybe they could make that a little clearer in the docs. Gerold, do you want to write a short answer here that clarifies my mistake so that I can mark it as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Surefire and Failsafe are quite similar this is also mentioned in Surefire's doc. However:

> will be removed in Failsafe 3.0.0

shouldn't affect Surefire.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mis-reading of the docs.